# LyX + fancyhdr issue on chapter

Tags: sectioning, lyx, fancyhdr

I have a LyX document in which I have set a standard header, as is

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[ER]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\thepage}
```

And I have created another style, that I want to use exclusively at a new section page

```
\fancypagestyle{secstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}
```

A new section needs to be on a new odd numbered page, and the "white page", when existent, must also be plain white. So I had this

```
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\stdsection}
```

and I've tried doing the following

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage{\thispagestyle{secstyle}}\stdsection}
```

and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: This works: `\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[ER]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{secstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{secstyle}\stdsection}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}`. What exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: The "white page", that sometimes is before the section page, is not on "secstyle" or plain white, plus the upper bar continues to appear on section pages. The pages following the "section" one don't get the header with section name, only with page number.

Comment: Did you try the settings in my example code? In particular, did you load the `emptypage` package and use `\pagestyle{fancy}`, as in my example code?

Comment: I could manage a workaround.
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
\clearpage
{\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}

Answer (score 1):

For the white page issue before new sections

```
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
\clearpage
{\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}
```

And I noticed the "secstyle" was identical to the "plain" style, so I could get what I wanted with this

```
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{\cleardoublepage{\thispagestyle{plain}}\stdsection}
```